# Should I remove DNC pins from symbol?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, kicad

Having downloaded the ECAD model for a sensor I want to use on my PCB, it appears that the included symbol contains a bunch of do not connect (DNC) pins. In fact 14 out of 22 pins are DNCs. Since I feel they unnecessarily clutter and obfuscate the schematic, I thought of altering the symbol to remove them.

Is this a good idea or do they serve any purpose on the schematic? What is the canonical procedure when dealing with such a (possibly auto-generated) symbol?

Comment: That is opinion based of course. But if you remove the DNC pins from schematic, you or someone else might not then remember or know why pins are missing and they do not know that the pins are Do Not Connect. Sometimes parts have really pins that have internal connections and are not supposed to connect to anything, and some parts have pins that simply have no connection and you can freely do whatever you want with those pins.

Comment: *do they serve any purpose on the schematic* <-- can't tell without a link to the specific device's data sheet. This implies it may not be a canonical question/answer.

Comment: @Andyaka The datasheet is this: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/682/Sensirion_CO2_Sensors_SCD4x_Datasheet-2321195.pdf

It says: "Do not connect, pads must be soldered to a floating pad on the customer PCB"

Comment: I'd possibly split the symbol into two parts with all the DNCs on symbol_a and all the important stuff on symbol_b.

Comment: For someone troubleshooting your pcb, having a schematic with pins shown as DNC can be just as informative (and important) as pins with net connections.  IMO, keep on the schematic, if possible.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, but I'm going to go against the grain (of opinions so-far) and say that you should leave them off. Whoever looks at the schematic next should have a copy of the device's datasheet to hand so they can see for themselves why there are "missing pins". Consider for example the standard single opamp in an 8-pin package - typically only 5 pins are used. How often do you see 3 more DNC pins hanging off an opamp symbol? Even when the opamp may have a pair of offset null pins, if they're not used in the circuit they're not typically drawn on the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be the same number of pins in the schematic symbol as are present on the PCB symbol or the tool may get confused. It would probably throw an error in any case.

It may be possible to use a PCB symbol that has more pins than the schematic, although I have not come across a CAD package where that is possible.

Even if it was possible, there could be a confusion factor.

It is sometimes possible to *hide* pins on the schematic symbol which would achieve the same result.

I would make a note on the schematic if that is done.

Comment: Hiding the pins is the recommended practice for KiCad at least.

Comment: In my experience with Altium and KiCAD, the programs will not object to the schematic symbol having fewer pins than the footprint, but WILL complain if the schematic symbol shows more pins than are in the footprint.